# How do I get the index of an item in a list and map it to a json object to perform an onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object which looks like the following:

```
[
    {
      thumbnail: 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff\u0026text=1',
      sources: [{
        src: 'http://view.vzaar.com/14749665/video'
      }]
    },
    {
      thumbnail: 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff\u0026text=2',
      sources: [{
        src: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4',
        type: 'video/mp4'
      }]
    }
]
```

I have already managed to grab each thumbnail image and append it inside the HTML using a forEach loop.

I now want to be able to click a thumbnail and it should console.log the video source url (`sources[0].src`).

How can i achieve this? Would I need to grab the index of the image clicked first, then correlate it with the object it lives in?

Comment: How about, when you append the thumbnail, you also attach a handler that logs the `src`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - great idea, I will need to use that src later on - i.e. The video src will change according to the index clicked on. I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Just add id field into each object like:

```
[
{
  id: 0,
  thumbnail: 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff\u0026text=1',
  sources: [{
    src: 'http://view.vzaar.com/14749665/video'
  }]
},
{
  id: 1,
  thumbnail: 'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff\u0026text=2',
  sources: [{
    src: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4',
    type: 'video/mp4'
  }]
}
]);
```

Then append the specified id of object to your each html tag as an attribute, like `data-id`. In click event get the value of `data-id` attribute and associate with id of object.

Comment: Can you put this into context please: "Then append the specified id of object to your each html tag as an attribute, like data-id. In click event get the value of data-id attribute and associate with id of object"

Comment: Something like this:
    <img data-id="{iterableObject.id}" src="{thumbPath}"></div>